# Node JS Discord Log guildMemberUpdate

Tags: node.js, logging, discord

I have tried various things and there are no errors but my bot has no response I tried to change my nickname, avatar, etc. there is no response here I am using node js please help me following my sample code. but when I attempt to carry it over to role adding and deletion, usernames, nicknames, and avatar changes, the bot fails to log this and crashes. How do I fix this issue within my code?

```
       //declare changes
       var Changes = {
        unknown: 0,
        addedRole: 1,
        removedRole: 2,
        username: 3,
        nickname: 4,
        avatar: 5
    };
    var change = Changes.unknown;

    //check if roles were removed
    var removedRole = '';
    oldMember.roles.every(function(value) {
        if(newMember.roles.find('id', value.id) == null) {
            change = Changes.removedRole;
            removedRole = value.name;
        }
    });

    //check if roles were added
    var addedRole = '';
    newMember.roles.every(function(value) {
        if(oldMember.roles.find('id', value.id) == null) {
            change = Changes.addedRole;
            addedRole = value.name;
        }
    });

    //check if username changed
    if(newMember.user.username != oldMember.user.username)
        change = Changes.username;

    //check if nickname changed
    if(newMember.nickname != oldMember.nickname)
        change = Changes.nickname;

    //check if avatar changed
    if(newMember.user.displayAvatarURL != oldMember.user.displayAvatarURL)
        change = Changes.avatar;

    //post in the guild's log channel
    var log = newMember.guild.channels.cache.get("channelID")
    if (log != null) {
        switch(change) {
            case Changes.unknown:
                log.send('**[User Update]** ' + newMember);
                break;
            case Changes.addedRole:
                log.send('**[User Role Added]** ' + newMember + ': ' + addedRole);
                break;
            case Changes.removedRole:
                log.send('**[User Role Removed]** ' + newMember + ': ' + removedRole);
                break;
            case Changes.username:
                log.send('**[User Username Changed]** ' + newMember + ': Username changed from ' +
                    oldMember.user.username + '#' + oldMember.user.discriminator + ' to ' +
                    newMember.user.username + '#' + newMember.user.discriminator);
                break;
            case Changes.nickname:
                log.send('**[User Nickname Changed]** ' + newMember + ': ' +
                    (oldMember.nickname != null ? 'Changed nickname from ' + oldMember.nickname +
                        + newMember.nickname : 'Set nickname') + ' to ' +
                    (newMember.nickname != null ? newMember.nickname + '.' : 'original username.'));
                break;
            case Changes.avatar:
                log.send('**[User Avatar Changed]** ' + newMember);
                break;
        }
    }
})
```